# MVC и подключение скриптов php

Tags: php, mvc

Здравствуйте, создал сайт с помощью MVC, теперь возник вопрос как к данному сайту подключать, картинки, скрипты оффлайн. Ведь он обрабатывает каждую ссылку в поисках контроллера, и не открывает ни картинки ни файлы, через полный путь.

Comment: дак может и не стоит уж прямо в каждой ссылке искать контроллер?

Comment: он не открывает ссылки потому что их нет. по идее вы в .htaccess должны были все ссылки направить на index.php поэтому по пути index.php/images.../ или что-либо еще у вас ничего не находит